# By exchanging two numbers in a series how many new series can I get?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let's say I have the folloing series: 2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10

How many unique ways to exchange the position of two numbers exists?
9-3-4-5-6-7-8-2-10 is one way to do it. This means that after exchanging two numbers you have a new series. I'm interested in knowing how many possible series exists.

Each number has the possibility of being exchanged with the 8 other numbers. This means that for each of the 9 numbers there is 8 ways of exchanging them. This means that the total number of series you can have from the first one is 9 x 8 = 72.
Is this reasoning correct? If not what is the correct solution.

Comment: That counts the pair $(2,9)$ distinctly from the pair $(9,2)$,  for example, so you should divde by $2$.

Comment: I do not consider 2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 and 9-3-4-5-6-7-8-2-10 to be the same should I still divide by 2 ?

Comment: Yes, but, starting from $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ you get to $9,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,10$ by switching $(2,9)$ or by switching $(9,2)$.

Comment: ah ok I get it now.